# Set actionbar icon for activity programatically?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to set the actionbar icon and title to be visible for an activity.

My app theme turns them off:

```
// styles.xml
<item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
```

In my activity:

```
public void onCreate() {
    ...
    ActionBar actionBar = activity.getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

The title and up arrow appear. But I can't get the icon to appear. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure but it might be better to use `@null` as value's item into your style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing [setDisplayShowHomeEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowHomeEnabled%28boolean%29).